# valueUpdate binding for input does not work

Tags: knockout.js

I have a page of settings with  elements. Each element has a bind to a ViewModel property.

I'm trying to implement editing and saving of settings.

```
function saveSettings() {
    var new_settings = {};
    new_settings.property1 = settingsViewModel.settings.property1();
    new_settings.property2 = settingsViewModel.settings.property2();
    new_settings.property3 = settingsViewModel.settings.property3();
    .........
}
```

If the content of  was not modified  - then it works well. But for inputs which content was changed by user I get an error "Property xxx of Object is not a function". Seems like my Viewmodel and bindings get broken after something is changed in  elements.

My binding is the following:

```
 <input data-bind="value: settings.property1, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
```

I also tried 'keyup', 'keypress', 'input' - nothing works.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to convert your view model to JSON to send to the server, can use ko.toJSON on it, or if you need more control, use the mapping plugin to do the same thing?

Comment: The properties of ViewModel are observable. But I'm trying to create a new object, fill it with values from my ViewModel and send this object  via POST request. So I don't need a new object to be observable, I just want to get data from observable property of my ViewModel

Comment: Why don't you just use ko.toJSON to get an object to post, or if you need more control, use the mapping plugin to do the same thing?

Comment: Your error message does suggest that whatever you are trying to get the data from isn't an observable, by the way.